# How to check Shape.ParentGroup?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

How to check if `Shape.ParentGroup` exists without resorting to `On Error` statement ?

This following code does not work:

```
Function IsMemberOfGroup(Shape_1 As Shape) as Boolean

    If Shape_1.ParentGroup Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "This shape is not a member of a group"
        IsMemberOfGroup = False
    Else
        Debug.Print "This shape is a member of a group"
        IsMemberOfGroup = True
    End If

End Function
```

The Shape Object properties in Excel VBA:
[image: VBA Shape properties]

*P.S.

Comparing `Shape.ParentGroup` to `Null` does not work either.*

Comment: When I recently did some work with shapes I found all the group objects (Name begins with Group) and iterated through their members - it's a workaround rather than a solution but it worked for me

Comment: In my question I specifically wrote: *"...without resorting to `On Error` "*

Comment: You may be barking up the wrong tree. Check this out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.parentgroup. *"Returns a Shape object that represents the common parent shape of a child shape or a range of child shapes."* You would need to know the name of the variable to which the *ParentGroup* was assigned and then check it with `Is Nothing`.

Comment: @TinMan Did a little test - Thought if it were that simple I wouldn't have worked around it myself.  I put 3 shapes onto a sheet and grouped them. Afterwards Sheet.Shapes.Count = 1 so none of the shapes on that sheet have this property set

Comment: Unfortunately the objective is not to list all shapes which are members of a group. The objective is to test whether ONE specific shape is a member of a group.  Of course one could iterate over all shapes to determie that but that is much slower than this abomination: 
http://ploxis.com/IsMemberOfGroup.txt

Comment: @TinBum  Yes, with 3 shapes grouped into one group, the `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count = 1`. However these 3 shapes inside that group can still be accessed individually by their names ...and then their `Shape.ParentGroup` is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Ricardo's answer in concert with the .Type property

```
Function IsGrpMember(dShp As Shape) As Boolean
    If dShp.Child = True Then
       If (dShp.ParentGroup.Type = msoGroup) Then
          IsGrpMember = True
       End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. That is the best solution because it is immune to a shape being a child of some other object than a `msoGroup`.  I hope that accessing `.ParentGroup` will never throw an error when `.Child = msoTrue`.  I was not able to find a case when `.Child = msoTrue` and `.ParentGroup` is inaccessible even for `CanvasItems` and `Chart` objects.

Comment: Yep, that's the risk George - I didn't have a setup that could test that rigorously.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the shape is a `Child`, then it has a `ParentGroup`

```
Function IsMemberOfGroup(Shape_1 As Shape) As Boolean

    If Not Shape_1.Child Then
        Debug.Print "This shape is not a member of a group"
        IsMemberOfGroup = False
    Else
        Debug.Print "This shape is a member of a group"
        IsMemberOfGroup = True
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately this misidentifies shapes which are not children of a group but are children of other objects as well, such as: a `Chart` or a `Canvas`, etc....  It generates different results as e.g. this abomination http://ploxis.com/IsMemberOfGroup.txt

Comment: When are shapes children of other objects (e.g. charts), when they are grouped? or does Excel identifies parts of charts as shapes? ...genuine question to see if I can check what you're expecting

Comment: The easiest way to see this is when the shapes are the children of the `Canvas` with  `ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).CanvasItems(1)` ...just like the VBA help has it in the example for the usage of the `Child` property.

Comment: In Excel I can't find a way to add a CanvasItems item

Comment: CanvasItems are in MS-Word

Answer (score 0):

Ricardo's Answer is an elegant solution. I'm a little off target to your exact question but, to list all Shapes on a sheet and say whether they are Stand-Alone shapes, or Group Shapes or members of a Group - This should work - as long as the Grouped Shape name begins with "Group" - which is the default

```
Sub ChkALLShapes()
   Dim xShp As Shape
   
   For Each xShp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
      If Left(xShp.Name, 5) = "Group" Then
         Debug.Print xShp.Name & " is a GroupShape"
         For K = 1 To xShp.GroupItems.Count
            Debug.Print xShp.GroupItems.Item(K).Name & " is a member of the Group"
         Next K
      Else
         Debug.Print xShp.Name & " is a StandAlone Shape"
      End If
   Next xShp
End Sub
```

Edit : Fixed a few typo's

Comment: The object names do not stay at defaut in my environment. Unfortunately the objective is not to list all shapes which are members of a group. The objective is to test whether ONE specific shape is a member of a group.  Of course one could iterate over all shapes to determine that but that is much slower than the following abomination:  
http://ploxis.com/IsMemberOfGroup.txt

Comment: What is that link you posted George. Not in English - Doesn't look relevant ?

Comment: It is a link to a badly written code that produces the desired results. The foreign language message is just an error message because the server is down atm.  I will let you know when it comes back up.

Comment: The server is back up